# Resolve Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException - should CDs share common redis cache?

Tags: xconnect, azure, redis

The logs of my site are getting full with `Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException`.

The site uses Sitecore 9.2 in a load-balanced setup on azure with CD1 in UK South and CD2 in UK West regions.
CDs are configured with custom autoscale, to allow increase instance from 1 to max of 2. If they scale up, both instances would share the same redis cache, however
CD1/CD2 have their own separate redis.sessions connection.

I followed the config changes outlined in [Walkthrough: Configuring a shared session state database using the Redis provider](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--configuring-a-shared-session-state-database-using-the-redis-provider.html) but am still getting the FacetOperationException. I could not find any info about whether it is correct to have two different redis services, or if CD1/CD2 should point to the same redis service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException exceptions can be safely ignored unless the Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.PatchFacetOperation exceptions are thrown.

You can see more **[here](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000613)** for additional details from Sitecore

**Note:** No need of creating extra Redis you must use the same Redis for all CDs and scales instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see any PatchFacetOperation exceptions, but there are rather more of the FacetOperationExceptions than I'm comfortable with. I'd like to be able to eliminate it altogether, if possible. Do you think that having the single Redis cache shared between the CDs/scales would reduce or eliminate the error?

Comment: I think it won't reduce or eliminate the error. As the error is occurring while same facet is trying update another interaction when the first one is still in process. Which means Sitecore Tracker or xDB is not able to do this simultaneously (this is  product limitation at the moment). Interaction flushing happens in batch and here the call is trying to break the process and update the facet for other interaction.  I think better way is to get this sorted from support team.